# Restlet Odata extension with HTTPS

Tags: android, https, restlet-2.0

I am trying to make a OData query to service through HTTPS with Restlet. First, I got "Not trusted server certificate" error. 
So I have followed http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates
and added the cert to keystore. Now I am able to create HTTPS request-response properly. But only when I use org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient class.

I dont know how to apply this for Restlet classes. Or can I somehow tell Restlet to use my own DefaultHttpClient.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

See this [wiki link](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html) on how to set Apache HTTP Client for restlet on Android.